# Recursive method that needs to access array where it left off

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am trying to create a method that resizes all images within a specific folder without disrupting the subdirectories formatting. I have two integer arrays that specify the width and height of the image that I want to be resized. I use a recursive call on the method to iterate through the folder and its subdirectories.

The problem is whenever I use the recursive call, it starts from the beginning of the width and height array when I want it to start where it left off. How do I fix this?

```
 resizeFiles(File[] folderToResize, String inputImagePath, int backgroundColor) throws IOException {

    int width[] = {36, 48, 72, 96, 96, 48, 72, 36, 48, 72, 96, 128, 48, 50, 80, 80, 1024, 40, 114, 57, 58, 60, 120, 180, 144, 72, 144, 76, 152, 87, 57, 114, 72, 144, 114, 57, 144, 72, 180, 128, 64, 173, 48, 62, 180, 800, 480, 320, 200, 480, 320, 1280, 720, 480, 320, 480, 240, 225, 2008, 1024, 1536, 1536, 768, 768, 960, 480, 640, 640, 640, 640, 320, 320, 64, 480};
    int height[] = {36, 48, 72, 96, 96, 48, 72, 36,48, 72, 96, 128, 48, 50, 80, 80, 1024, 40, 114, 57, 58, 60, 120, 180, 144, 72, 144, 76, 152, 87, 57, 114, 72, 144, 114, 57, 144, 72, 180, 128, 64, 173, 48, 62, 180, 800, 480, 320, 200, 480, 320, 1280, 720, 480, 320, 480, 240, 225, 1536, 783, 2008, 2008, 1004, 1004, 640, 320, 960, 960, 1136, 1136, 480, 480, 64, 800};

    for (int i = 0; i < folderToResize.length; i++) { 
        if (folderToResize[i].isDirectory()) {
            resizeFiles(folderToResize[i].listFiles(), inputImagePath, backgroundColor);
        } else {
                System.out.println("File Pathway: " + folderToResize[i].getAbsolutePath() + "     Width: " + width[i] + " Height: " + height[i]);
                resize(inputImagePath, folderToResize[i].getAbsolutePath(), width[i], height[i], backgroundColor);
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
I changed my code to this, but now it won't pass through the directories properly. Odd because I didn't change anything how it passes through directories. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 resizeFiles(File[] folderToResize, String inputImagePath, int backgroundColor, int width[], int height[], int previousIndex) throws IOException {       //won't walk through the directories properly

    for (int i = 0; i < folderToResize.length; i++) {
        if (folderToResize[i].isDirectory()) {
            resizeFiles(folderToResize[i].listFiles(), inputImagePath, backgroundColor, width, height, i);
        } else {
            System.out.println("File Pathway: " + folderToResize[i].getAbsolutePath() + "     Width: " + width[previousIndex] + " Height: " + height[previousIndex] + " Index: " + previousIndex);
            resize(inputImagePath, folderToResize[i].getAbsolutePath(), width[previousIndex], height[previousIndex], backgroundColor);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the relation between the image sizes in your arrays and the files? What if there are more files than entries in your arrays?

Comment: Add a parameter into your recursive method that contains the previous index you were at in the last method call.

I.E) resizeFiles(File[] a, String b, int c, int previousIndex)

Comment: @JosephD I tried this, and then added a previousIndex = i; right after the print statement and it's still not working properly, any other suggestions?